# samba server as network storage for VHD discs

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, samba, vhd

I am looking for solution for 128-256 diskless HPC servers, want to create one vhd file with Windows system on it, sysprep and create 256 branching differential discs for each computational node in the network.

We just got first 24 nodes here and I have managed to install free HyperV server on USB stick, but my virtual machine cannot access the drive on network share, not in Windows shared folder not on CentOS Samba.

As the virtual machine is owned by some local non administrative process w/o privileges i always finish with cannot access error (the user running machine have not enough privileges to write on the shared drive). I have played with it for a while and Microsoft recommends to add all Hyper-V servers to the domain. But I believe that sharing it on public Samba is easier, well only if I could make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dude.

Set up one machien with a FAST io System and Server 2012 as ISCSI target, use the Server 2012 integated ISCSI target, set up PXE based boot to ISCSI, finished. No flumsy USB sticks.

Then read up on how to make the stuff Domain members and how to set up central Hosting for VHD files - the permissions needed are not really that hard to find in the documentation. But you NEED a Domain. Your believe it is easier are totally contradicted by you not gtting it to work - plus a lot of higher functionality depends on Domains to get it right easily.

Comment: I am kinda one man shop and I am not so keen to buy more licenses. Tried to add one Hyper-V server to the domain, worked well, I will try if vhd on the server will work now, but I would still prefer to keep them on the Samba.

Domain means more work to set it up and actually tried it before. I cannot see the point really, I have 50 identical computers right now, 2 servers ad 5 workstations. That is really simple, i cannot see any benefits I will get from moving to domain, except more work and system works now ok, all except the vhd hosting.

Comment: And more control. SCCM, SCVMM are great for that.

Comment: GPO's and the like make administering all of that easier. Even keeping samba, and joining to the domain, you get a lot of benefits.